# What size PERT/PEX tubing to replace supply lines for cast iron hot water radiators?

Tags: heating

I'm building a basement apartment in a large 1911 Foursquare home. Part of this is replumbing our 20 cast iron (hot water, not steam) radiators. The old steel, asbestos wrapped supply pipes were hanging far too low for walking clearance. They have been cut out of the ceiling and disposed of.

The old steel pipes used a 2-pipe system where the supply and return that left the radiator were in two large 2" pipes and then split off into smaller "branches".  18 of the radiators used 3/4" pipe. 2 larger ones used 1". Everything I read indicates that the modern way to redo this is "home runs" to each radiator individually, converge at a manifold, and while you're at it, make zones for each floor.

I plan to use a PERT tubing product called HeatFlex made by Oil Creek in lieu of PEX-AL-PEX. https://www.supplyhouse.com/Oil-Creek-HF9051000-1-2-HeatFlex-PE-2708-PERT-Tubing-1000-ft-Coil

My question is: what size PERT/PEX do I use to replace the old steel pipe and more importantly how do I go about determining this?

I'm no engineer and admittedly very overwhelmed calculating GPM, BTU, heat loss, etc. My basic assumption is that if the ID of the new lines match the old, we should be fine. However, since I'm doing home runs to each, I'm aware I’m increasing the volume of water in the system quite a bit. It's unclear to me if that will create a problem and if it influences what size pipe I choose. I've read multiple forums insisting 1/2" is sufficient, but many others insisting I should match the ID of what was already there.

For context, I’ve attached a schematic I drew below of how I intend to route the new pipes in each joist/bay.

[image]

Comment: i used loopCAD to model my house then it does all the heatloss calcs for you.